# how to revert aspTextBox to default value when validation fails

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a webForms website that uses an asp CustomFieldValidator to check if text has changed in a textbox. When it fails I would like the textbox to return to its default text. Is there a way to do this?
I tried in the server validation code

```
protected void PasswordChangedValidator_ServerValidate(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
{
    if (PASSWORDTb.Text.Contains("●") && PASSWORDTb.Text != "●●●●●●●●")
    {
        args.IsValid = false;
        PASSWORDTb.Text = "●●●●●●●●";
    }
    else { args.IsValid = true; }
}
```

and clientside code:

```
<asp:CustomValidator ID="PasswordChangedValidator" runat="server"
       ErrorMessage="message" ControlToValidate="PASSWORDTb"
       ClientValidationFunction="passwordValidate()" Style="color: red;" 
       OnServerValidate="PasswordChangedValidator_ServerValidate"
       SetFocusOnError="true"></asp:CustomValidator>

function passwordValidate() {
    var pswdText = doc.getElementById('<%=PASSWORDTb.ClientID %>').value;
    if (pswdText.indexOf('●') >= 0) {
        if (pswdText == "●●●●●●●●") {
            return true;
        }
        doc.getElementById('<%=PASSWORDTb.ClientID %>').value = '●●●●●●●●';
        return false;
    }
}
```

Is there something obvious that I am missing?

Comment: You have the code that sets it commented out:  //PASSWORDTb.Text = "●●●●●●●●";

Comment: Not 100% sure what you're trying to achieve here but I get the feeling you might want to look at using `placeholder` on your textbox as an alternative. Ie. `MyTextBox.Attributes.Add("placeholder", "Type password");` then you don't need to worry about validating that value as "Type password" will appear in the textbox while it's blank.

Comment: @RudyTheHunter sorry forgot to uncomment again for the purpose of this post. I've edited to reflect what I actually tried.

Comment: @HugoYates If a user deletes a circle or adds something to the password box that is invalid then I want the text property to return to '●●●●●●●●' when the error message from the custom validator is shown.

Comment: So when the user goes to add their password they must manually clear the TextBox? If the TextBox is set to `TextMode="Password"` then it's value is automatically masked. It looks like you're reinventing the wheel a bit here.

Comment: I am a little, but this is for automated file delivery onto a server and(understandably) the Password textMode always shows as empty when you postback, which gives me issues when I try to update the DB table with the value from there. Also, my team needs to know that there is data in that field.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Hugo Yates for pointing me in the right direction with attributes. 
My solution was to add passwordChanged() to the onblur attribute of my TextBox.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="PASSWORDTb" OnBlur="javascript:passwordChanged()"...></asp:TextBox>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function passwordChanged(){
       if (pswdText.indexOf('●') >= 0) {
          if (pswdText != "●●●●●●●●") {
             doc.getElementById('<%=PASSWORDTb.ClientID %>').value = '●●●●●●●●';
          }
       }
</script>
```